# Joining tables and displaying columns with different conditions

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I have 2 tables:
CTU contains columns 'course_id', 'user_id', and 'date'
NU contains columns 'name' and 'id'

user_id in table CTU has the same info as 'id' in table NU.

I want my output to display the following:
name | date where course_id = 1 | date where course_id = 2

I can get the first 2 columns to appear with a simple query, but I don't understand SQL JOIN's and subqueries very well so I'm having a hard time getting the last column to display.

Comment: plz provide some data samples..

Answer (score 0):

One way to pivot out the date like that is to use a group by and an aggregate function. How about something like this:

```
SELECT
     n.name
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN c.course_id = 1 THEN c.date END) AS course_1_date
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN c.course_id = 2 THEN c.date END) AS course_2_date
FROM CTU as c
JOIN NU as n
  ON c.user_id = n.id
GROUP BY n.name
```